# How are F-bialgebras defined?

Tags: category-theory, definition, universal-algebra

First, does such a notion exist?

If so, would it be as trivial as the triple $(S,\alpha, \beta)$, where $(S,\alpha)$ is an F-algebra and $(S,\beta)$ is an F-coalgebra?

I'm assuming there would be more that needs to occur, such as some interaction between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I haven't found much information out there that I can understand.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bialgebra

Comment: There's a similar but different notion called a [dialgebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dialgebra).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More generally, given two endofunctors $T$ and $F$ on a category $C$, we can define a *$(T,F)$-bialgebra* to be an object of $C$ equipped with the structure of a $T$-algebra and an $F$-coalgebra, i.e. just a triple $(S,\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha\colon TS\to S$ and $\beta\colon S\to FS$.

But this is a very broad notion. As you expect, we usually want some relationship between the $T$-algebra structure and the $F$-coalgebra structure. The usual way of doing this is the notion of $\lambda$-bialgebra, where $\lambda$ is a *distributive law* (of $T$ over $F$): a natural transformation $\lambda\colon TF \to FT$.

A *$\lambda$-bialgebra* is a $(T,F)$-bialgebra $(S,\alpha,\beta)$ such that $\beta \circ \alpha = F\alpha\circ \lambda_S \circ T\beta$ (I recommend drawing the diagram for yourself).

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly the answer I wanted! Time to go find some papers 